# Insert NULL if value matches the value of another column

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have a table : "MyTable" and I have two columns in it : "val" and "val_new".

Now I want to insert new value into "val_new" but if the values are equal('val' and 'val_new') I want to insert NULL instead.

```
----------------------
| id | val | val_new |
----------------------
| 1  |  5  |  NULL   |
----------------------
| 2  |  6  |  NULL   |
----------------------
```

Lets have this table for example.

Now :

```
UPDATE myTable mt
SET mt.val_new = '5'
WHERE mt.id = '1';
```

I want the value of val_new to remain NULL or be updated to NULL instead of '5'.

EDIT: 
I want to UPDATE existing values not INSERTING new rows.

Comment: why not just add both values, then handle if they are the same when queried later?

Comment: I think, you can use a trigger

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Thanks you are correct. I want to UPDATE exisitng values. I edited my question. Sorry for the missunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not have to insert a record rather you will have to update the existing one. If you run your insert command a new record will be created. So you table will have

```
----------------
|val | val_new |
----------------
| 5  |  NULL   |
----------------
| 6  |  NULL   |
----------------
|    |         | <-- if val = val_new
----------------
|    |   6     | <==if val<> val_new.
```

I guess you dont need this output. So the best option is to update the columns.

You can use case statement,

```
update <yourtable>
set val_new =case 
                when  val_new= val   then 
                NULL 
               else val_new
             end
```

Comment: Yes you got my point I wanted to UPDATE existing rows but for some reason I made an INSERT example. I edited my question. Thanks for the answer it is correct !

Comment: val_new = val should be val = number and else val_new should be number.  The way you have it is if the user updated it, then wanted to do another update to check it.  You want to check if the number being updated into it matched val.  It is adding another step.

Comment: OP has requested a condition when val and val_new are same then update it with null. He just gave an  example of 5. So hard coding with 5 is not needed.

Comment: I saw the BUT and I interpreted that to be all in one step.  OP Wants to update value (val_new) with value 'number' BUT if number (aka the val_new value) is the same as val then update NULL INSTEAD.  I guess BUT and INSTEAD is what really caught me.  I guess it is a matter of interpretation :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems a bit confusing in some parts.  The way your word it seems like a new row is to be created but it also seems like you want to update it?  Hopefully this is what you wanted :)

```
 UPDATE testVal Set val_new = CASE WHEN val = 5 THEN NULL ELSE 5 END
```

`testVal` is your table.  If you wanted to use a different number just replace both `5` with the number of your choice.  I used `5` because you used it in your example.

Comment: Exactly you got my point I don't even know why I made an example with INSERT .. The whole thing is that I want to UPDATE existing values there is nothing to INSERT. But God knows why I used this verb so much and made an example with it  (INSERT).

Comment: @lazarov haha. I think it's just because of how we grow with the english language. We learn null is basically nothing so if something is null then it's empty and you insert into empty while when it comes to sql/programming languages null is most defiantly a thing and not just emptiness.